# CNN (Tensorflow) for classification of Iris data set (multilevel)

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, convolution

I have seen multiple example of CNN for MNIST data where each record is one image(representing in matrix form - say - 28x28 and one channel for color). For simple classification of Iris - each records is also matrix (1x4 and no channel)

Does CNN apply for Classification of Iris data set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: no, it does not.

Convolutional networks exploit **spatial relations**, meaning that your features need to have spatial meaning. This relation can be 1D (like audio), 2D (images), 3D and so on., but arbitrary set of unrelated features (like length and width of petals, represented in iris dataset) do not correspond to these kind of specification. Technically there is no problem - you could run CNN on this data, but you should expect rather terrible results.

Comment: I wish you answer could cover the technical part - "you could run CNN on this data" as well.